# Tailor MCollective agent actions based on the machine's facts

Tags: ruby, puppet

Lets say I have a MCollective agent named "foo" with action "bar", in the logic of the action I want to do X when the fact "chicken" is "true", and do Y when the fact "beef" is true.

Basically, how do you access facts from a MCollective agent?

Answer (score 1):

You can just access the configured fact source like:

```
if PluginManager["facts_plugin"]["yourfact"] == "foo"
  # do something
else
  # do something else
end
```

Do that anywhere in your agent u need access to the facts.

hth, if not please ask on the mcollective users list on google groups